# Error when using cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and accounts-oauth together?

Tags: meteor, cordova-plugins

I have a meteor project that uses a number of cordova plugins, including cordova-plugin-inappbrowser, which is pretty standard. Now I wanted to add accounts to this project and added `accounts-google`. However, after doing that, I now get an error when running meteor:

```
Error while running for mobile platforms: Error running                            
/Users/cfritz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.1fae8uc++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-inappbrowser':Error: Uh oh!
"/Users/cfritz/work/typhone/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/inappbrowser/InAppBrowser.java" already exists!
at Object.module.exports.common.copyNewFile
(... many line like that ..)
Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" for android
```

I've narrowed it down to being an issue only when both `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` and `oauth` are installed. It seems that somehow `oauth` is already trying to install the `InAppBrower.java` file, and indeed when adding or removing the `oauth` package and restarting meteor, I get a message "Installing Cordova plugins".

Question: why/where does the `oauth` package specify anything about cordova? why does it install cordova plugins? Is there a way to avoid this conflict?

---

Update: I see now that the `oauth` package actually [specifies](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/oauth/package.js)

```
Cordova.depends({
  'cordova-plugin-inappbrowser': '1.0.1'
});
```

so that answers the first part of my question. But I'm still stuck on how to get these two packages to work together. Adding the same version:

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.0.1
```

does *not* work (`Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`$ meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser@0.5.4`

It worked for me.